# Find the nth lucky number generated by a sieve in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program in Python which will generate the nth lucky number according to the [lucky number sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_number). I'm fairly new to Python so I don't know how to do all that much yet. So far I've figured out how to make a function which determines all lucky numbers below a specified number:

```
def lucky(number):
    l = range(1, number + 1, 2)
    i = 1
    while i < len(l):
        del l[l[i] - 1::l[i]]
        i += 1
    return l
```

Is there a way to modify this so that I can instead find the nth lucky number? I thought about increasing the specified number gradually until a list of the appropriate length to find the required lucky number was created, but that seems like a really inefficient way of doing it.

**Edit:** I came up with this, but is there a better way?

```
def lucky(number):
    f = 2
    n = number * f
    while True:
        l = range(1, n + 1, 2)
        i = 1
        while i < len(l):
            del l[l[i] - 1::l[i]]
            i += 1
        if len(l) >= number:
            return l[number - 1]
        f += 1
        n = number * f
```

Comment: Use the algorithm to create a list with the first ten million lucky numbers then pickle it.  Do this once. Then all your program has to do is read in the list and index into it.

Answer (score 4):

> I came up with this, but is there a better way?

Truth is, there will *always* be a better way, the remaining question being: is it *good enough* for your need?

One possible improvement would be to turn all this into a generator function. That way, you would only compute new values as they are consumed. I came up with this version, which I only validated up to about 60 terms:

```
import itertools


def _idx_after_removal(removed_indices, value):
    for removed in removed_indices:
        value -= value / removed
    return value


def _should_be_excluded(removed_indices, value):
    for j in range(len(removed_indices) - 1):
        value_idx = _idx_after_removal(removed_indices[:j + 1], value)
        if value_idx % removed_indices[j + 1] == 0:
            return True
    return False


def lucky():
    yield 1
    removed_indices = [2]
    for i in itertools.count(3, 2):
        if not _should_be_excluded(removed_indices, i):
            yield i
            removed_indices.append(i)
            removed_indices = list(set(removed_indices))
            removed_indices.sort()
```

If you want to extract for example the 100th term from this generator, you can use [itertools nth recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def nth(iterable, n, default=None):
    "Returns the nth item or a default value"
    return next(itertools.islice(iterable, n, None), default)

print nth(lucky(), 100)
```

I hope this works, and there's without any doubt more room for code improvement (but as stated previously, there's *always* room for improvement!).

Comment: in Python3, you need to specify integer division:
value -= value // removed

Comment: looks like the last two lines to avoid duplicates and sort removed_indices are unneeded since i is always incremented

Answer (score 0):

With numpy arrays, you can make use of boolean indexing, which may help.  For example:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(10)
>>> print a
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

>>> print a[a > 3]
[4 5 6 7 8 9]

>>> mask = np.array([True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False])
>>> print a[mask]
[0 2 4 6 8]
```

Here is a lucky number function using numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

class Didnt_Findit(Exception):
    pass

def lucky(n):
    '''Return the nth lucky number.

    n --> int

    returns int
    '''

    # initial seed
    lucky_numbers = [1]
    # how many numbers do you need to get to n?
    candidates = np.arange(1, n*100, 2)
    # use numpy array boolean indexing
    next_lucky = candidates[candidates > lucky_numbers[-1]][0]

    # accumulate lucky numbers till you have n of them
    while next_lucky < candidates[-1]: 
        lucky_numbers.append(next_lucky)
        #print lucky_numbers
        if len(lucky_numbers) == n:
            return lucky_numbers[-1]
        mask_start = next_lucky - 1
        mask_step = next_lucky
        mask = np.array([True] * len(candidates))
        mask[mask_start::mask_step] = False
        #print mask
        candidates = candidates[mask]
        next_lucky = candidates[ candidates > lucky_numbers[-1]][0]
    raise Didnt_Findit('n = ', n)

>>> print lucky(10)
33

>>> print lucky(50)
261

>>> print lucky(500)
3975
```

Checked mine and @icecrime's output for 10, 50 and 500 - they matched.

Yours is much faster than mine and scales better with n.

Answer (score -1):

```
n=input('enter n ')
a= list(xrange(1,n))
x=a[1]
for i in range(1,n):
    del a[x-1::x]
    x=a[i]
    l=len(a)

    if i==l-1:
        break

print "lucky numbers till %d" % n
print a  


lets do this with an example.lets print lucky numbers till 100
put n=100
firstly a=1,2,3,4,5....100
x=a[1]=2
del a[1::2] leaves 
a=1,3,5,7....99
now l=50
and now x=3
then del a[2::3] leaving a =1,3,7,9,13,15,.....
and loop continues till i==l-1
```

Comment: could you provide a bit of explanation to this code? to improve your answer and help future readers understand

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Donald Duck You or someone else flagged this.  While I agree it's not a great answer, I think the right approach is to downvote not to flag.

Comment: @SamHartman I know, I didn't flag it. I reviewed it in the [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16428516) and chose Looks OK.